# How to find the minimum voltage difference in a time series data after which a new waveform starts?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a lot of time series data, one example could be found under this link:
https://github.com/nazmul1001/test/blob/a23d4d8122bfeddbfa107bd6c3f2b1526ecc9073/3_8_2_3_8_2-351.csv

If I plot a graph using this code below, it looks like the following image.

```
    df = pd.read_csv('3_8_1_3_8_1-1.csv')
    df.columns = ['time', 'voltage']
    diff_1 = df['voltage'].diff()
    plt.figure(100,figsize=(10,4))
    plt.plot(df['time'], diff_1)
    plt.xlabel('Time in μs')
    plt.ylabel('Volatage in V')
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]
In this image, I am assuming the red marked line is the shortest, I want to find out what is the exact voltage difference for this shortest line. Basically, I am trying to find out the minimum voltage difference in a measurement after which a new waveform starts.

I know that there are a lot of smaller voltage difference which is near to 0 and looks like the noise, so I am trying to find out, the minimum voltage difference above 2. For this example, what is the voltage difference which is above 2 and the minimum among all other waveform.
Could anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, that will give you the answer:

```
diff_1[abs(diff_1.values) > 2].sort_values(key=abs)
```

which returns

```
4971    2.023046
6719    2.043277
3139   -2.073623
141    -2.083738
7138   -2.103968
          ...   
640    -3.550446
890    -3.560562
7139   -3.732521
4889   -4.288858
5139   -4.450702
Name: voltage, Length: 66, dtype: float64
```

So, the minimum voltage difference greater than 2 is `2.023046`

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for, but I am little confused because in the graph it shows the minimum voltage difference after which a new waveform starts is somewhere near 2.8 or 2.9 but, in your solution it is 2.02, could you tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: The issue could be the lines were so close to each other the big lines overlies the smaller lines. Try to plot this `plt.plot(diff_1[4970:5000])` which takes a small portion and you'll see there are actually many points around `2`